# error using resnet model using transfer learning

Tags: python, model, tf.keras

Here is a cell of my code I'm trying to run on kaggle:

```py
# resnet model using transfer learning
resnet_model = Sequential()
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(include_top= False,input_shape=(224,224, 3), pooling='avg',weights='imagenet')
# resnet_model.trainable = False
```

---

This is the error I'm getting:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
many errors related to this
```

(I'm working on Tire Texture Image Recognitio dataset from kaggle)

Could someone help me debug this problem?